# Can I run code after right after the injection has been completed?

Tags: android, dagger-2

I've got this simple class in Dagger 2:

```
@Inject public Bus bus;

@Inject
public TwitterAppModel() {
    bus.register(this);
}
```

This will not work because `bus` is `null` in the constructor function. Can I intercept somehow (for example with an annotation) when the injection is complete and `bus` is not null?

## What I've tried:

It works if I do the following:

```
@Inject
public TwitterAppModel(Bus bus) {
    this.bus = bus;
}
```

And in my Module:

```
@Provides
@Singleton
TwitterAppModel provideTwitterAppModel(Bus bus) {
    return new TwitterAppModel(bus);
}
```

I dont really like this solution, it makes refactorings harder, and I dont care about injection order. Other IOC frameworks that I used had some kind of event/annotation that I could use to execute code when injection has finished.

## I am looking for something like:

```
@Inject public Bus bus;

@Inject
public TwitterAppModel() {
}

@OnIjectComplete
public void onInit() {
    bus.register(this);
}
```

This would make the code more clear, have less code in config classes (Dagger has enough already), this class would be easier to remove, if I wanted to add a new @Inject that I want to use at the startup no need to edit in 2 places etc.

Comment: Please read some guides and tutorials and try to ask a specific question. This looks like you didn't even try to understand what dagger is or how it works. You're using the constructor wrong and just scattered some @Inject as if you are expecting magic to happen

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Sorry, I am not an expert in Dagger. I though StackOverflow was a site where people ask and answer questions, not insult each other if they don't know something. I have edited my question to show that I do know how Dagger works to an extent.

Comment: I did not mean to be insulting. Now after you edited the question there is a better problem statement. But you're still mixing up constructor injection vs modules. You don't have to write any `new` calls yourself using dagger, just in some edge cases, you know? And you should *either* annotate your fields and use field injection *or* annotate your constructor to use constructor injection, not both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @OnInjectComplete annotation that you are looking for already exists. It's called @Inject! Any methods with @Inject will be called after the @Inject fields have been populated. If the method takes parameters, those parameters will be injected.

So try:

```
@Inject public Bus bus;

@Inject
public TwitterAppModel() {
}

@Inject
public void onInit() {
    bus.register(this);
}
```